# Can I force a method of an abstract class to return something?

Tags: php

I have defined an abstract class and a method which is supposed to return the name of a template file. The user subclasses this abstract class and implements that method to return the template file name. But the problem is, that there happens no warning or whatever if the user just does not return anything.

How could I make this sure? The code that calls this method belongs to the framework, so I could do some fancy stuff with `settype($returnVal, 'string')` maybe, if that helps? Are there better solutions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In PHP, you cannot "force" a method to return anything -- and it's not possible, even with abstract classes/methods, nor interfaces.

The best you can do is indicate that the implementation should return something, using a comment -- but you cannot force people to do so :

```
/**
 * @param string $a blah blah
 * @return int The return value blah blah
 */
public function my_method($a);
```

Of course, if you are calling this method *(the implementation)* from your framework, you can check what has been returned, and throw an Exception if it doesn't correspond to what you expected...

And here is a quick example of how this could be implemented :

```
class ClassA {
    /**
     * @param string $a blah blah
     * @return ClassB The return value blah blah
     */
    public function my_method($a) {
        echo 'blah';
    }
}

class ClassB {
    // ...
}


$a = new ClassA();
$returned = $a->my_method(10);
if (!$returned instanceof ClassB) {
    throw new Exception("Should have returned an instance of ClassB !");
}
```

Here, as the method doesn't return an instance of `ClassB`, the exception will be thrown.

Comment: well but it would be possible to check the return value, right?

Comment: @openfrog : yes, of course -- but you'll have to code that yourself : it's not enforced by PHP (I edited my answer while you were posting your comment -- I'll edit again with an example)

Comment: That's great. Thanks!! You practically answered two of my questions at once :-)

Comment: @openfrog : Yeah, when I saw your question about detecting if an object is an instance of a class, I thought "hey, I just used the instanceof operator in another answer" ^^

Comment: Not true anymore since php7.1, see @constantin-galbenu answer below, which should be accepted answer. It does not answer about abstract method though

Answer (score 10):

In PHP 7 it is possible to force a method to return an instance of a class like this:

```
class MyClass
{
    public function getData(): MyData
    {
        return 1234; //TypeError!
    }
}
class MyData
{
}
```

In this way, the following code is invalid and throws a `TypeError`:

```
$obj = new MyClass();
$obj->getData();
```

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d3b8e36d3549c24f55728b5fb841496576a2e076).

Comment: This can be done in a abstract method as well :     abstract public function getData(): MyData;

Answer (score 3):

The only way I can think to do this is create a `public final` method in the parent class that the calling code will use, and a `protected` method which will be called by the `public final` method. The `protected` method contains the functionality, and the `public final` method validates the return value of the `protected` method.

```
class A {

    public final call_this($param) {

        $return_value = $this->extend_this($param);

        // validate $return_value
        if( $return_value == '' )
            throw new Exception("uh-oh! Don't return an empty string!");

        return $return_value;

    }

    protected extend_this($param) {

        // default behavior

        return $whatever;

    }

}

class B extends A {

    protected extend_this($param) {

        // new behavior

        return ''; //whoops!

    }

}

$b = new B;
$b->call_this("testing testing 123");
//exception!
```

This can be a little confusing for the person extending the class though, if you try something like this, make sure it is well documented.

`public final` is a public method that cannot be overridden, in case you didn't know. Also note that this will only work in PHP 5.0.0 or better.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no way to achieve type hinting for return values in PHP. Since PHP 5, there is limited hinting for [function parameters](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php).

But even if there were, what you are trying to do is not a job for type hinting. What happens if the string I return is empty? You will need to check for the return value wherever the method is called, and react appropriately.